# Discord Bot embed msg

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js, bots

I need to add the image of bot in the right side of embed msg.

```
if (message.includes('help')) {

msg.channel.send({
  embed: {
    title: "xxxxxx",
    color: 3447003,
    description:"Enter **agjgj** to know \n\n Enter **jfjk** for \n\n Enter **ufuy** to get"
  }
});
```

}

also how to tag the user in this code.

Answer (score 0):

You can tag the user in a next message after the embed.
`msg.channel.send(message.author.toString())`

And to add a thumbnail (image on the right) in the embed:

```js
embed: {
    title: "xxxxxx",
    color: 3447003,
    description:"asdasd",
    thumbnail: {
        url: "https://asd.com/asd.png"
    } 
  }
```

To use a file hosted on the server as a thumbnail:

```js
const file = new Discord.MessageAttachment('./asd.png');
message.channel.send({files: [file], 
    embed: {
        title: "xxxxxx",
        color: 3447003,
        description:"asdasd",
        thumbnail: {
            url: 'attachment://asd.png',
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Instead of adding url is there any other way like adding the image and sharing the location.

Comment: @AlexyPThomas I think it is possible by attaching a file to the embed and then use it as an URL for the thumbnail (or for image). You can check the information how to do it on the embeds page [link](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/embeds.html)

Comment: I was checking this and doing it. But its not getting reflected. Anyway thanks. I am using the url.

Comment: I have just tried it and it worked you can check my edited answer. But still in my opinion using external image hosting is better (i.e. imgur).